# SQL need help fixing/modifying/finishing code

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling to figure out the issue with my code exercise solution. I think I started it well and have a good foundation but it won't run (getting an invalid identifier error). Maybe my code is too messy or doesn't make sense? Not sure. If you guys can think of a solution of a better way to fix this code solution/answer the query, let me know.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer. Question and ERD are below. Thank you in advance

> For every stock exchange, display the symbol of the stock with the highest total trade shares. Show the stock exchange name, stock symbol and total trade shares. Sort the output by the name of the stock exchange and the stock symbol.

```
WITH HighestTradeVolume   
    (SELECT COUNT(trade.shares) total_trades,
            stock_listing.stock_symbol AS "Stock symbol",       
            stock_exchange.symbol AS "Stock Exchange Symbol",          
            stock_exchange.name AS "Stock Exchange"    
    FROM stock_exchange       
         JOIN trade    
              ON trade.stock_ex_id = stock_exchange.stock_ex_id    
         JOIN stock_listing
              ON stock_listing.stock_id = trade.stock_id
              AND stock_listing.stock_ex_id = trade.stock_ex_id     
    GROUP BY stock_exchange.name, stock_exchange.symbol, stock_listing.stock_symbol
        ORDER BY stock_exchange.name, stock_exchange.symbol, stock_listing.stock_symbol)    
    HAVING SUM(trade.shares) = (SELECT MAX(SUM(trade.shares))    
                                 FROM trade );
```

[image: ERD]

Comment: So what is the error?  Please edit the question

Comment: I did. Its an invalid identifier error.

Comment: Help us help you - paste the eact text of the error

Comment: Not an invalid identifier but also wrong: `MAX(SUM(trade.shares))` -- you cannot nest aggregation functions.

Comment: Okay, in the "HAVING" line. How would you do it separate then? I want to display the highest total trade shares and I only know that as SUM (to get total) and MAX (to get the highest value)

Comment: Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Can you use window functions in your homework?

Comment: I don't think we learned that yet. This is just a beginner SQL class. We just started learning about in-line views and sub-queries

Comment: In the future, please make your Q complete, including error messages there, rather than asking readers to go thru an ever extending string of comments to understand your problem completely ;-/ . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra bracket end of the ORDER BY line and also missing bracket at the end.

```
ORDER BY stock_exchange.name, stock_exchange.symbol, stock_listing.stock_symbol --) Extra   
HAVING SUM(trade.shares) = (SELECT SUM(trade.shares) FROM trade ) --Applying MAX is not required.
) --Missing
;
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out

Comment: You are welcome @bstapies. Let me know if that helped.